# Is this arm movement a military gesture?

Tags: the-amber-project

> “Yes, sir,” said the soldier. He held up his hand again, but this time he didn’t make a fist. Instead, **he pointed his fingers out and moved his entire arm in a circular motion.** Without a word, the soldiers left the room.

He moved his entire arm in a circular motion. What does this arm signal mean?

Comment: I've noticed you have several questions which have good answers, but are unaccepted. If possible, could you either accept them, as per the [tour], or provide feedback on why the answers are not correct?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In [army parlance](https://armypubs.army.mil/epubs/DR_pubs/DR_a/pdf/web/ARN2747_TC%203-21x60%20FINAL%20WEB.pdf), this signal means "traveling" (e.g. "*let's go"*).

[image]

J.N. Chaney is himself a military man ([USAF](https://www.fantasticfiction.com/c/j-n-chaney/)) and would be very familiar with these hand and arm gestures.

Comment: You beat me to the answer, but I was going to call it out as "Rally."  Note that you're quoting TC3-21.60, which uses a flat hand for "Halt" instead of a fist.  I'm guessing it's the older hand signals as shown [here](https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-basic-infantry-hand-signals).

Comment: @DavidW - I assumed it was going to be "Move out", but this is typically given as a command to follow the leader, not to get moving on your own

Comment: Fair enough; I've never been most closely associated to anything military than having relatives enlist, so I'll defer to any potentially better knowledge. :)